# Affinity Designer - Resize curve without transforming it

Tags: affinity-designer

I have a **curve** that is orignally **240x240** in a file that has as much size.

I want to resize the path to `140x140`.

I tried to create a 140x140 file  and decreased the width and heigh of the curve to 140. However, when exporting this file as SVG (for export) file, though the size of the SVG changes, but the `path` is nested in a `<g>` element that has `matrix transform`

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(0.490184,0,0,0.490184,0.276721,0.254908)">
```

Is there any way to resize the path such that it does not appear in a g element when exported?